# Combining post categories and link categories?

Tags: categories, links, hierarchical

So as to get a single index of both internal posts and external links on the same or related topic/subject matter, is it possible to combine post categories and link categories?  I would like to be able to drill down through a single hierarchy, and find all collected information on the topic, whether external or internal to the site.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can [register a custom taxonomy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy) for more than one object type:

```
register_taxonomy( 'topic', array( 'post', 'link' ), /* more arguments */ );
```

But be aware that the [link manager will be removed in 3.5](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/21307), so it might be better to use a custom post type for links. You can register a shared taxonomy for that too.